# Minimal tasty preparation of raw chayote

Tags: fruit, seasoning, raw

I've got a couple of [chayotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chayote) that I'd like to try raw. I've never had chayote before, but from what I've read, they're pretty bland when raw and require significant seasoning to be tasty.

How do you prepare raw chayotes minimally to make them tasty as a dish?

Comment: The wikipedia article you linked to mentions using them raw in salads, salsas, and marinated in lemon or lime juice. Those are pretty good suggestions - for the most minimal recipes, I'd look around for simple salads containing summer squash, especially marinated ones using lemon or lime. The absolute minimal form would be squash, lime, and salt. You might want more, though. (I'd post this as an answer, but I can't personally recommend any of the recipes I've found.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shredding or slicing, sprinkling with salt and resting for about 10 minutes, then squeezing out excess liquid is a good start. Then mix in lime juice, plate, sprinkle with ground chilies for a bit of heat and color.